# What is the difference between linear and geodesic interpretation?

Tags: geometry, gis, gml-geographic-markup-lan

While trying to understand the difference between LineStringSegment and GeodesicSegment, I concluded that the difference is the interpretation of the segment (correct me if I am wrong).

Could someone explain the difference between **linear** and **geodesic** interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeodesicString uses geodesic interpolation -- that is, interpolation over the surface of the planet. If you had a geodesic segment from the north pole to the equator, the result would be an arc following the surface; if you had a linear segment, the result would be a line tunneling underground.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.